# ¿Como guardar en SQL Server tipo de dato Geometry desde Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012

Buen día...
Tengo una tabla definida (SQL Server 2012) así;

```
CREATE TABLE cliente(
 id [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 codigo [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 nombre [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 apellidos [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 direccion [varchar](100) NULL,
ubicaciongeo [geometry] NULL,
 telefono [varchar](100) NULL,
 email [varchar](100) NULL,
 foto [image] NULL,
 estado [bit] NOT NULL)
```

Luego tengo un formulario (Windows Forms de Visual Studio 2015 - C#) donde se inserta esos datos.

Para insertar utilizo un método y en el un procedimiento almacenado así:

```
            string sql = "EXECUTE sp_ClienteInsertar @id, @codigo, @nom, @ape, @dir, @ubigeo, @tel, @ema, @fot, @est";

            SqlCommand cdo = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion.SQLServer2012);
            cdo.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cdo.CommandText = sql;
            cdo.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Codigo;
            cdo.Parameters.Add("@codigo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = Codigo;
            cdo.Parameters.Add("@nom", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Nombre;
            cdo.Parameters.Add("@ape", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Apellidos;
            cdo.Parameters.Add("@dir", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Direccion;
        cdo.Parameters.Add("@ubigeo", SqlDbType....... ).values = UbicacionGeometrica;
            cdo.Parameters.Add("@tel", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Telefono;
            cdo.Parameters.Add("@ema", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Email;
            cdo.Parameters.Add("@fot", SqlDbType.Image).Value = Foto;
            cdo.Parameters.Add("@est", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Estado;

            conexion.SQLServer.Open();
            cdo.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conexion.SQLServer.Close();
```

El detalle es que no puedo como guardar este valor (no hay tipo de dato):

```
cdo.Parameters.Add("@ubigeo", SqlDbType....... ).values = UbicacionGeometrica;
```

Y menos como en el formulario en un TextBox ingresar ese dato.

Mi pregunta es:

¿Que valor ingresar desde un TextBox (u otro control) y como guardar en la base de datos SQL Server?

P.D.: Necesito guardar un posición geográfica de un cliente y luego trazar una ruta de guía con ello.

Comment: estas usando entity data framework?

Answer (score 0):

1. Debes referenciar Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, lo puedes hacer instalando el paquete de nuget con el mismo nombre.
2. El parámetro lo defines así:

   cdo.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ubigeo", SqlDbType.Udt));
   cdo.Parameters["@ubigeo"].UdtTypeName = "geometry";

Saludos,

Comment: Y desde el control sea textbox u otro, como ingresar el formato del valor?